# SEO friendly .htaccess always lead me to home page

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have problem with seo friendly url. I've try to change my url with .htaccess and off course I have problem.

My link in header for my contact page is like this:

```
index.php?=contact
```

So I wrote rules in .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact index.php?=contact
```

And off course changed my link in header to be like this:

```
contact
```

And now when I click on contact on header I get nice url like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact
```

But website lead me always to home page (index.php).

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this clear, and now working. I just changed link, and put `page`. Static link working now for me, but how to write to dinamic link. For instance, my link is like this:

```
<a href=index.php?page=kategorije/$row[id_cat]/$newname>{$row['name']}</a>
```

$newname give "-" instead empty space between words.

And this kind of link give me this url:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page=category/3/The-Name-Of-Shop
```

How to write .htaccess to get:

```
www.mywebsite.com/The-Name-Of-Shop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here give this a try and see how it works. 
You have an `=` between `index.php?contact` Try removing that.

If you want to make all your links URL friendly and not just `contact` you can do this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

**EDIT:**

Your array is blank because you're not passing anything to it. I can't see how you check in your `index.php` file but you typically pass parameters as `item=value` like `index.php?page=contact`. You're not giving it an `item` using `index.php=contact` so your array is blank with the mod_rewrite.

Based on the info I have, if you used the variable as the `item` and `value` like below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?$1=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Go to http://www.yoursite.com/contact

You'll get this from PHP `$_GET`

```
Array ( [contact] => contact )
```

But if you do this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Then go to http://www.yoursite.com/contact

Then you'll get this from PHP `$_GET`

```
Array ( [page] => contact )
```

Then you check it like

```
if($_GET["page"] == "contact"){
//do whatever 
}else{
 //show homepage
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the .htaccess rules I can see. It's your PHP setup.

Comment: No, didn't work. Maybe is problem in this. On main page I collect variable from URL, and which page will be shown depends of which variable will be collect. If variable doesn't exist then will be shown home page. Obviously here doesn't exist that variable "contact" and show me home page. When I don't use .htaccess, URL get variable (index.php?=contact) on the end "contact" and open contact page.

Comment: If you browse to this link `index.php?=contact` you get your contact page?

Comment: Check the setup of your PHP file and try to do a `print_r($_GET);exit;` and see what it shows when you try to browse to your contact page with the mod_rewrite. So you can see what's in the GET request.

Comment: He give me empty array, and because of that he call home page. In that array I must have "contact" to open contact page. So why .htaccess don't give link like I wanna to my server, and give him opportunity to grab "contact" from URL?

Comment: First did you resolve the original problem? If yes, did my answer help you resolve the original problem?

Comment: I did like you told me. Instead index.php?=contact, I wrote index.php?page=contact, and write code in .htaccess RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L].Now working.Look answer above yours.

Comment: OK can you accept this answer then? You need to start a new question for your for new problem instead of creating an answer for it. Then I or someone can help you with the new URL you want.

Comment: Accept answer as complete? :) The check mark on this page below the 0.

Comment: FYI you build reputation points if you mark an answer as accepted if the answer helped your situation. Try and **accept** answers to your questions. People help you but you don't accept the answers. Accept means to click the check mark under the zero. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/about